# How to hide an element based on sibling's css property value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

```
<div id="mc-response">
    <div id="mc-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    <div id="targeted">Success</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to show "#targeted" element when "#mc-success-response" element's display is "block". How we can achieve this?

Comment: Do we need to check this once when the page loads ?

Comment: @ShravanDhar No, after submitting a form.

Comment: Could you edit the title to be accurate? #mc-success-response isn't the parent of #targeted. They are siblings. What changes the display from none to block?

Answer (score 0):

If the targeted div display is none in the beginning (or has an opacity of 0 etc), we can use the MutationObserver class in JS

```
var observerDiv = document.querySelector("#mc-success-response")
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function() {
        if (observerDiv.style.display === "block") {
            document.querySelector("#targeted").style.display = "block"
        }
        else document.querySelector("#targeted").style.display = "none"
    });    
});

observer.observe(observerDiv, { attributes : true, attributeFilter : ['style'] });
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const elementMcSuccessResponse = document.getElementById(
      "mc-success-response"
    );
const targetedElement = document.getElementById("targeted");

const btn = document.getElementById("button");

 btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (elementMcSuccessResponse.style.display === "none") {
    /// mc-success-response is hidden
    elementMcSuccessResponse.style.display = "block";
    targetedElement.style.display = "none";

  } else if (elementMcSuccessResponse.style.display !== "none") {
    /// mc-success-response is visible
    elementMcSuccessResponse.style.display = "none";
    targetedElement.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```html
 <div id="mc-response">
    <div id="mc-success-response">mc-success-response</div>
    <div id="targeted" style="display: none">Success</div>
    
    <button id="button">click</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.